# ReactJS - push method with useState array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The purpose here is to have an array of channels id where I can populate him with information that is coming from my firebase.

I have my component like this:

```
export default function Component() {

const [channelsId, setChannelsId] = useState([])

// and I call this function passing my state
  useEffect(() => {
    getChannelsIds(someId, channelsId, setChannelsId)
  }, [])
```

**The function:**

```
export const getChannelsIds = (someId, channelsId, setChannelsId) => {
  try {
    firestore.collection("channels").where("someId", "==", someId).get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        setChannelsId([...channelsId, doc.data().id])
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('Error while trying to get the channel.')
  }
}
```

It's not working, because my channelsId state is being override and I only have the last channelId, **console.log screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: In your first code snippet you're not *calling* a function, you're *declaring* a different one *with the same name*.

Comment: @JaredSmith my mistake, copy and paste, I edited

Comment: you can't just have random side effects (like querying a backend) in a pure functional component, you'll have to wrap that call with a useEffect hook.

Comment: @JaredSmith in my code the function is being called in a useEffect hook, sry I just edited.

Comment: Why are you calling your setter in a loop, instead of doing something like `setChannelsId([...channelsId, ...querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data().id)])`? You're triggering however many unnecessary re-renders, and any React state that depends on the previous state should pass in a callback rather than a value: state updates are async: `setChannelsId(channelsId => [...channelsId, ...querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data().id)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

```js
export const getChannelsIds = (someId, channelsId, setChannelsId) => {
  try {
    firestore.collection("channels").where("someId", "==", someId).get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        setChannelsId(ids => [...ids, doc.data().id]);
      })
    })
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('Error while trying to get the channel.')
  }
}
```

Or even better you could create first an array with the new data and only update the state once.

```js
export const getChannelsIds = (someId, channelsId, setChannelsId) => {
    try {
      firestore.collection("channels").where("someId", "==", someId).get().then(querySnapshot => {
          const newChannelIds = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data().id);
          setChannelsId([...channelsId, ...newChannelIds);
          });
      }
      catch (err) {
        toast.error('Error while trying to get the channel.')
      }
    }
```